# Java Applet calling javascript function with return value

Tags: java, javascript, null, applet, return

I have been trying to wrap my head around this. Please help me where I screwed up.

Similarily to calls on this url:
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/applet/call-javascript-function-from-java-applet

I made calls from within my Java Applet's init and start methods to the browser.

Javascript goes like:

```
function getHHandler() {
    console.log("handler requested from applet");
    return HHandler.handler();
}

HHandler.instance = null;

function HHandler() {
    ...
}

HHandler.prototype = {
    doStuff : function() {
    }    
};

HHandler.handler = function() {
    if(HHandler.instance == null)
        HHandler.instance = new HHandler();
    return jsb.instance;
};
```

Here's my debug-ready method from the applet - nothing fancy at least it should be:

```
private Object getHandlerObject() {
    Object jo = browser.call("getHHandler", null);
    log("call getJSBHandler():" + jo);

    return jo;
}
```

I've been through oracles examples, countless sites, tutorials, documentation and all point to the same call and eval methods.

**Experience**
What happens is when the applet calls to the getHHandler javascript function -- I can see the console log in the browser seeing that the action did actually happen, however the return statement from javascript never makes it back to the Java code. So Java is left with a null object which I have no use of.
I even double-checked just to be sure that right before the return statement the js var is not null.

I can understand why 
    browser.call("HHandler.handler", null);
would freak out and throw a NotAFunction exception, but in this case everything seems to go smoothly, but the return value.

```
<applet id="appletId" archive="../path/to/applet.jar" code=com.package.Main.class width="1" height="1" mayscript></applet>
```

It doesn't even matter if the applet is self-signed or not signed at all. Mayscript is added - not that it makes a difference.

Any suggestions/inputs?

Comment: *"It doesn't even matter if the applet is self-signed or not signed at all."*  It also doesn't make any difference.  A 'self signed' applet is now considered to be unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Which Java version are  you using? Recently *racle changed [lots of things](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) in applets. All applets need to be signed with an official certificate (self signing does not suffice).
And also see the [LiveConnect changes since 7u45](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/liveconnect_changes_in_7u45).

Now

a) use an official certificate or

b) if you use and up-to-date java try an older one and see whether it works. If it is the case then you know where to start...

Comment: Java Plug-in 10.60.2.19
Using JRE version 1.7.0_60-b19 x64
I did try to use literal objects (int and string) for return values, which interestingly enough show up in java. Javascript hangs on the line HHandler.handler(); line as if code after that doesn't get executed (not even logs).

Comment: You didn't answer the full qestion: Did you try an official certificate? If not a) try with an older java b) lower your java security slider to medium c) add your url to the exception site list and d) last but not least set the attributes right